# MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback is not working with javascript:__doPostBack

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a gridView and its records can be long. I have a command field to update the records.

When I click "Edit", the command button makes a javascript postback:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('gridSubCategories$ctl02$ctl00','');
```

But even if I set `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"`, the page is not scrolling to the previous point after the postback.
How can I get this to work?

Comment: Are you using an ajax updatepanel? I have encountered this issue when using ajax and I am not entirely sure why. For whatever reason have a look at post number 2 in the above link which will show you how to do your own maintain position in a simple javascript function.
http://forums.asp.net/p/948134/1149902.aspx#1149902